# Select multiple divs but play different audio with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

I'm currently trying to create a soundboard just to learn some more advanced jQuery techniques.

Currently, each div is associated to a jQuery function that represents a sound. When the div is clicked, the respective sound is played. In it's current state, I have each function written as separate functions, which overtime, will lead to redundant code.

Curious if there is a way to abstract the function to build out one function that represents any div click that will then initiate the appropriate audio file.

See code below:

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
        <h1>Soundboard Trials</h1>
        <div id="boxes">
            <li id="nyan"><audio src="song.mp3"/></li>
            <li id="duck"><audio src="duck.mp3"/></li>
            <li id="duck"><audio src="cat.mp3"/></li>
        </div>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
#wrapper {
    width: 800px;
    margin: auto;
}

#boxes {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 50px auto;
    list-style: none;
}


#boxes li {
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #aaa;
    margin: 5px;
    float: left;
    cursor: pointer;}
```

jQuery

```
$(function(){
$("#nyan").click(function(){
    var audio = $('audio')[0];
    if (audio.paused){
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
    }
});

$("#duck").click(function(){
    var audio = $('audio')[1];
    if (audio.paused){
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
    }
});
$("#cat").click(function(){
    var audio = $('audio')[2];
    if (audio.paused){
        audio.play();
    } else {
        audio.pause();
    }
});

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try:

```
<div id="boxes">
    <li id="nyan" class="audioclick"><audio src="song.mp3"/></li>
    <li id="duck" class="audioclick"><audio src="duck.mp3"/></li>
    <li id="duck" class="audioclick"><audio src="cat.mp3"/></li>
</div>

$(function(){
    $('#boxes').on('click','audioclick',function(){
        var $eq = $(this).eq(),
            audio = $('audio').get($eq);

        if (audio.paused){
            audio.play();
        } else {
            audio.pause();
        }
    });
});
```

This should grab the index number of the item on click, then choose the respective audio element based on that index number (since its a one-to-one matching).

Answer (score 0):

You could base your selection on the context (the container) of the list.
As in:

```
$(document).on("click.mySoundboard", "#boxes li", function (event) {
    var $audio = $("audio", event.target);
    console.log($audio.attr("src"));

    // etc...
});
```

[Working Example - jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jw7e9/1/)